# How to insert an answer widget on tkinter? - project with 2 files

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have python project with 2 files. One creates the GUI and other is used to make some simples maths with the entries that are inserted on the GUI file. My problem is: how can I put the answer on the GUI?
The example that I create is to insert the value of "a" and "b" and the program will retrieve the sum of a + b. I want that the answer appears on the GUI like: "The sum of a + b:" & the value. Right now I just print on the terminal.
Here is my code:

GUI_file

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from main import *

firstWindowResults = []

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

firstWindow = Tk()

w = 300
p = 300

ws = firstWindow.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
hs = firstWindow.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (p/2)

firstWindowTitle = Label(firstWindow, text="Calculate a + b")
firstWindowTitle.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)

firstInput = Label(firstWindow, text="Value of a")
firstInput.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=10, pady=10)

secondInput = Label(firstWindow, text="Value of b")
secondInput.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=10, pady=10)

firstEntry = Entry(firstWindow)
firstEntry.grid(column=2, row=3, padx=10, pady=10)

secondEntry = Entry(firstWindow)
secondEntry.grid(column=2, row=4, padx=10, pady=10)

firstWindowValues = [firstEntry, secondEntry]

def validateFirstWindowValues():
    clear()
    firstWindowResults.clear()
    invalid = 0
    for value in firstWindowValues:
        if value == firstEntry:
            if float(value.get()) <= 0:
                entry = firstWindowValues.index(value) + 1
                messagebox.showerror("Valor inválido", "Ver linha  " + str(entry) + "!")
                invalid += 1
                break
            else:
                firstWindowResults.append(value.get())
        if value == secondEntry:
            if float(value.get()) <= 0:
                entry = firstWindowValues.index(value) + 1
                messagebox.showerror("Valor inválido", "Ver linha  " + str(entry) + "!")
                invalid += 1
                break
            else:
                firstWindowResults.append(value.get())
    if invalid == 0:
        dims(firstWindowResults[0], firstWindowResults[1])

nextButton = Button(firstWindow, text="Seguinte", command=validateFirstWindowValues)
nextButton.grid(column=1, row=9, padx=10, pady=10)

firstWindow.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, p, x, y))
firstWindow.mainloop()
```

main_file

```
def dims(firstEntry, secondEntry):

    global va, vb

    va = float(firstEntry)
    vb = float(secondEntry)

    c = va + vb

    print(c)
```

Comment: Why not display that information on a `Label`?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to return the result of `dims()`:

```py
def dims(firstEntry, secondEntry):
    global va, vb
    va = float(firstEntry)
    vb = float(secondEntry)
    c = va + vb
    # return the result
    return c
```

and then show the result inside `validateFirstWindowValues()` using a `Label` widget:

```py
...

# create a Label for the result
result_label = Label(firstWindow)
result_label.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

def validateFirstWindowValues():
    #clear()
    firstWindowResults.clear()
    invalid = 0
    for value in firstWindowValues:
        if value == firstEntry:
            if float(value.get()) <= 0:
                entry = firstWindowValues.index(value) + 1
                messagebox.showerror("Valor inválido", "Ver linha  " + str(entry) + "!")
                invalid += 1
                break
            else:
                firstWindowResults.append(value.get())
        if value == secondEntry:
            if float(value.get()) <= 0:
                entry = firstWindowValues.index(value) + 1
                messagebox.showerror("Valor inválido", "Ver linha  " + str(entry) + "!")
                invalid += 1
                break
            else:
                firstWindowResults.append(value.get())
    if invalid == 0:
        # show the result in result_label
        result_label["text"] = f"The sum of a + b is {dims(firstWindowResults[0], firstWindowResults[1])}"

...
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: I just don´t get it one thing. How do you import the value of c to the GUI file?

Comment: I don't import the value of `c`. I get it from the returned result of calling `dims()`.

Comment: okok, I got it. Sorry to borrow, but if now instead of just c I have also variable d (d=a-b). How can display also the value of d?

Comment: You can return both `c` and `d` in `dims()`.

Comment: I created a new result label and I´m getting:

Comment: The sum of a + b is (15, 5); The sum of a - b is (15, 5)

Comment: You can store the returned result into two variables first, for example `a, b = dims(...)`. Then use these two variables in the result strings of the two labels.